# how to give parameter of get method to used of this parameter in post method of this page

Tags: java, ajax, jsp, servlets

how to get data

```
$.ajax({
    url : "ShowLeaveManagerServlet",
    //url : "LeaveStatusServlet?empId="+empId,
    type: "GET",
    contentType: "application/json",
    success : function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        //var   result  = $.parseJSON(data);
        //var table4 = $("#sendtable");

        var table4 = $('#sendtable');
        $.each($.parseJSON(data), function(idx, obj) {
            console.log(obj);    
            table4.append('<tr><td class="lid">'
                + obj.leaveId
                + '</td><td>'
                + obj.empId
                + '</td><td>'
                + obj.leaveType
                + '</td><td>'
                + obj.stDate
                + '</td><td>'
                + obj.endDate
                + '</td><td>'
                + obj.reason
                + '</td><td>'
                + obj.status
                + '</td><td><select id="status" name="status" onchange="changeStatus('+obj.leaveId+')"><option value="Acceapt" >Acceapt Leave</option><option value=" Reject"> Reject</option></td></tr>');
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: not clear question

Comment: can you explain what exactly is the question? Give some expected output/example?

Comment: what are the parameters you are sending ? what are you trying to do ?

Comment: if do you have a problem with response please post the server side code otherwise we can't help you